# Docusign Composite Template unexpected behavior

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

I'm a Java developper and I'm trying to use docusign composite template but I have some issues.
I created 3 template A,B,C on docusign which have one different document each and 1 signature area on each document, the signature of the document A is on the first page, for B it's on the third page.

What I would like to do, is create an envelop with 3 new documents, and apply a template on each document. So I upload document 1 which match with template A, document 2 with template B etc..

But currently when I do that. It seems that the template are merged and the first document have several templates in it, so 2 signatures area, one on the first page (Template A) and one on the third page (Template C).

When I did that, the envelop is created with the 3 documents:
But document A have template A and B,
document B does not have any template.
document C have template C.

I tried to do so with API with this request

```
{
  "status": "created",
  "templateId": "TEMPLATE_D",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "xx",
      "name": "xx",
      "roleName": "Signer"
    }
  ],
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "x",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "doc",
        "name": "DOC_A'.doc",
        "order": "1"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "xx",
                "name": "xx",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Signer"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "TEMPLATE_A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "x",
        "documentId": "2",
        "fileExtension": "doc",
        "name": "DOC_B'.doc",
        "order": "2"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "xx",
                "name": "xx",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "Signer"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "4"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "3",
          "templateId": "TEMPLATE_B.doc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "3",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "x",
        "documentId": "3",
        "fileExtension": "doc",
        "name": "DOC_C'.doc",
        "order": "3"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "xx",
                "name": "xx",
                "recipientId": "5",
                "roleName": "Signer"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "6"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "5",
          "templateId": "TEMPLATE_C"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is use the template D for the envelop.
Substitue Doc A in the template A with a new doc A' to Keep only the signature AREA (the documents are quite the same except some wordings). Same with B' and C'

Comment: You tagged this as java but didn't post any java code.  Is this specific to java or even a programming question?

Comment: Yes it's a programing question, I pasted only the result of the code

Answer (score 0):

So to put it another way, you have a server template that you want to include in your envelope, but substitute a different document for the one in the template? And you want to do this 3 times (3 different server templates).

Try the following.

```
  "envelopeDefinition": {
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
      {
        "document": {
          "filename": "anchorfields v2.docx",
          "documentId": "1",
          "name": "anchorfields v2.docx"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
          {
            "templateId": "71a66510-ad60-49c8-b830-6db89072fc91",
            "sequence": "1"
          }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "2",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "roleName": "signer1",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "1"
                },
                {
                  "roleName": "signer2",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "2"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { // composite template 2
        "document": {
          "filename": "anchorfields v2.docx",
          "documentId": "2",
          "name": "anchorfields v2.docx"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
          {
            "templateId": "71a66510-ad60-49c8-b830-6db89072fc91",
            "sequence": "3"
          }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "4",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "roleName": "signer1",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "3"
                },
                {
                  "roleName": "signer2",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "4"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { // composite template 3
        "document": {
          "filename": "anchorfields v2.docx",
          "documentId": "3",
          "name": "anchorfields v2.docx"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
          {
            "templateId": "71a66510-ad60-49c8-b830-6db89072fc91",
            "sequence": "5"
          }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "6",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "roleName": "signer1",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "5"
                },
                {
                  "roleName": "signer2",
                  "email": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "recipientId": "6"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: It's not really like that. In your exemple, you miss the fact that there are 3 different documents and 3 differents template. I want to subsitute the document for each template.

There are 4 template in docusign :
Template A with doc A
Template B with doc B
Template C with doc C
Template D with no documents but only email and subect

What I want is use the template D for the envelop
Substitue doc A with a new doc A' in template A to Keep only the signature AREA (the documents are quite the same execpt some wordings). Same with B' and C'

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a template's "email." The email of the sender can't be set dynamically. The email of the recipient(s) is set for each recipient. Email subject is set at the top level. See [`emailSubject` attribute](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_emailsubject)

Comment: We create an empty template with juste the subject and the email filled because we don't want it to be stored in the code, but we want that other people can change it directly on docusign